# No PushNotification received ( pushwoosh )

Tags: android, cordova, pushwoosh

I have implemented everything sucessfully as per the docs and got my device registered with pushwoosh:

[image]

and heres the code :

```
<script>

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var pushNotification;
function onDeviceReady() {  
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
pushNotification.register
(successHandler, errorHandler,{"senderID":"10524986381","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});    

}
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
switch( e.event )
{
    case 'registered':
     if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
     {

         PushWoosh.appCode = "F653A-0888C";
         PushWoosh.register(e.regid, function(data) {
                     alert("PushWoosh register success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                 }, function(errorregistration) {
                     alert("Couldn't register with PushWoosh" +  errorregistration);
                 });
    }
     break;
       }
  }
 function successHandler (result) {
   }
  function errorHandler (error) {
   }
</script>
```

but unfortunately I am unable to receive PushNotifications onto the device once sent.

Please help,Thank you !

Comment: Did you ever solve it? The code looks fine, maybe the way you send notification needs to be looked at too.